# Is it bad form to use getRequestURL() in the Servlet API in order to respond with an absolute URL in a Location header?

Tags: http, rest, grails, servlets

I am designing an RESTful API for our product and have encountered the need for asynchronous actions. The recommendation from several books is to use the 202 response code and provide a link to the "status" of the action in the `Location:` header.

While trying to implement this in a Grails environment, developers recommended using Grails ability to create links automatically ([docs here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html)). The problem is that then an administrator has to define the `grails.serverURL` in a configuration (which is just one more thing to go wrong).

I proposed that we use the request to reflect back the appropriate URL by simply replacing the requested resource "/rest/foo" with the newly created "status" resource "/rest/bar/status-42".  Is it appropriate to use [HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) in this way? If so, can you comment on the reliability of getRequestURL() (I've heard disturbing reports)? If not, why not, and any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not bad form. I have no evidence to back this up but the absence of people of people screaming, "NO! NO! Anything but THAT!" and the javadocs I linked to. I'll reply back here and change my answer if it turned out to be a bad idea :)

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Try it on a discussion forum instead.